# echo click on the button to run and go to website

Tags: php

How can I make the buttons have image and to go on other website link in echo script but not to see address ?

here is my script : 
`echo "<td><button class='btn btn-info btn-mini'>".$myrow['url']."</button></td>\n";`

I stood and looked for but I can not find the correct formula how to do. i need help here. please

Comment: What do you mean by not see address? That is exactly how the browser works, by following links.

Comment: to no see the address on the image here http://postimg.org/image/jrvhd34cp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are probably looking for i guess is the `a` tag. A simple link would be:

```
<a href="some_link.html"> Title </a>
```

taking you to `some_link.html` whenever you click on the `Title`

In your case you could use something like:

echo " Title ";

To put an image you need the `img` tag. ie:

```
<img src="test.jpg">
```

or if you have the image in the $row array

```
echo "<img src='".$row['image']."'>";
```

---

**Solution as OP's question:**

```
echo " <td><a href='".$myrow['url']."'><button class='btn btn-info btn-mini'>web</button></td>\n";
```

---

Comment: thanks for the help I fix the problem  here:      echo "                                                <td><a href='".$myrow['url']."'><button class='btn btn-info btn-mini'>web</button></td>\n";

Comment: You are welcome. Please take some time to further research html/php/mysql if you are using this in a live environment.

Comment: thanks for help frend, I will but I dont have tutore to help me :P

Answer (score 0):

You will need to:

`echo "<td><a href='.$myrow['url']'><button class='btn btn-info btn-mini' /></a></td>\n";`

Currently you're setting the button's **content** to the url from $.myrow['url'], but you actually need to set the a tag's target, rather than the button content.

Comment: your is not good, sory here what I wanted  echo <td><a href='".$myrow['url']."'><button class='btn btn-info btn-mini'>web</button></td>\n";

Comment: yes, yours is not good in encho you dont need " after href= corect is singel ' not " in echo. Look at script. But thank you for the effort, frend

Comment: Indeed, but you shouldn't copy and paste answers, just look at the specifics of it and alter your code accordingly, in which case you should've been looking to just change the position of $.myrow['url'] -> Updated answer regardless in case anyone else decides to foolishly copy and paste without checking first

Comment: and hwo do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use javascript for that

```html
<img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/eightyshades/512/18_Close-128.png" id="a" />
<script>
  document.getElementById('a').onclick = function() {
    window.location = 'http://google.com';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: here I dont have java, only php I fix the problem. thanks. you have up what I fix from "Kypros"